# How to decompose a image with MSB/LSB method?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to decompose one image into two images , for example and for simplicity if I have a 8 bits gray-level image and the first image carry the first 4 bits(MSB) information and the second image carry the last 4 bits(LSB) information, and only if I both have these two images then I can restore the original image by putting these bytes together and pixel by pixel.The lost bits of each image could be filled with same value like 0000 or 1111 .

The problem is I have no idea what kind of methods and library is much suitable for this purpose and will be more flexible if I would like to try more complex way to decompose images.

Thank you for your suggestion or examples.

Comment: use PIL or OpenCV. If it doesn't need to be fast, use for loops otherwise make a vectorized function

Comment: Thank for your suggestion , I already found some good example by PIL/opencv and it worked.